# Looping through std::vector and deleting elements results in out of range exception

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a `std::vector` array (`vectorArr`) of objects. Have 2 threads, 1 push objects `vectorArr` array and other work with them. Some objects must be deleted from it when I end work with them. So I just add such objects index number to other `std::vector<int>` (`DeleteList`) and then iterate over it and erase objects from `vectorArr` by the saved index, but some times I'm getting an out of range exception. I don't understand why that happens.

```
std::vector<int> DeleteList;
int index = 0;
for (auto &data : vectorArr)
{
    if (data.frames < 150) {
        data.frames++;
        //some code here
    }
    else DeleteList.push_back(index);
    index++;
}

if (DeleteList.empty())
    return;

for (auto &dIndex : DeleteList) {
    if (dIndex < vectorArr.size())
        vectorArr.erase(vectorArr.cbegin() + dIndex); // out of range exception
}
DeleteList.clear();
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The vector shrinks when you erase from it.

Comment: ah, i get it. Thank you. @molbdnilo

Comment: You might want to [look up the *erase-remove idiom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), which is an easy and efficient way to delete multiple elements from a vector.

Comment: If you delete backward this could work, but anyway erase-remove idiom is more efficient.